# How can I get this @extend error resolved?

Tags: css, node.js, npm, sass, gulp

I am trying to learn more about Gulp and found code for a site that uses it and am trying to run it on my computer.

Here is a link to the github repo https://github.com/ArjanJ/arjan-jassal-site

When I get everything installed and run `npm start` I receive the following error:

> You may not @extend an outer selector from within @media.
>   You may only @extend selectors within the same directive.
>   From "@extend %u-heading-3" on line 299 of src/assets/css/site/views/_details.scss

I know that from [this article](http://thesassway.com/intermediate/understanding-placeholder-selectors#Limitations) you cannot use extend beyond @media queries but I cannot find where that is in the code listed above. Could anyone help me resolve this error? Thank you.

Comment: Just to clarify: is this your starting point with gulp? This babel file is not representative of a typical gulp setup, and there's just a lot going on. Did you start by googling "gulp intro"? I haven't read https://css-tricks.com/gulp-for-beginners/ but it looks promising

Comment: The media query is introduced [here with the `@include bp(small)`](https://github.com/ArjanJ/arjan-jassal-site/blob/master/src/assets/css/site/views/_details.scss#L267). The error in your post gives you the line number of the extend inside that media query.

Comment: @steveax Do you have any suggestions on what I could do to fix it?